# amazon s3 delete function in php not working

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to delete a specific object from my bucket. I used this code for deleting. But this not working for me.

```
    use Aws\S3\S3Client;
$s3 = S3Client::factory(array(
    'key'    => CONTENT_KEY,
    'secret' => CONTENT_SECRET
));
$keyname     = "/".CONTENT_PATH."/magazinename";


if ($s3->deleteObject(CONTENT_BUCKET, $keyname)) {
echo "Deleted file.";
}
```

I got an error that:

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to Guzzle\Service\Client::getCommand() must be an array

Answer (score 2):

```
$bucket = '*** Your Bucket Name ***';
$keyname = '*** Your Object Key ***';

$result = $s3->deleteObject(array(
'Bucket' => $bucket,
'Key'    => $keyname));
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/DeletingOneObjectUsingPHPSDK.html

Comment: i tried this but i got this as output                                    Guzzle\Service\Resource\Model Object
(
    [structure:protected] => 
    [data:protected] => Array
        (
            [DeleteMarker] => 
            [VersionId] => 
            [RequestId] => 111111111111
        )

)                                                                     when i look in to s3 browser it doesn't deleted

Comment: The $keyname should not begin with a slash. The [Model object](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/feature-models.html) you are seeing implies a successful deletion, you are just deleting the wrong key.